# Use current Vector2 variable and add value?

Tags: xna

If I have a Vector2 variable, like this:

```
Vector2 fuellevelPosition = new Vector2(50, 750);
```

and I want to use that position for another object and also add 30 pixel to the X value for the position of the new object, how do I do that?

This didn't work:

```
Vector2 fuellevelTextPosition = new Vector2(fuellevelPosition.X + 30, fuellevelPosition.Y);
```

EDIT:

The code I use in the beginning of Game1.cs

```
 Vector2 fuellevelPosition = new Vector2(50, 750);
 Vector2 fuellevelTextPosition = new Vector2(fuellevelPosition.X + 30, fuellevelPosition.Y);
```

Comment: It should work, but you can also do this Vector2 fuellevelTextPosition = fuellevelPosition + new Vector(30, 0); And what does it mit it didnt work?

Comment: you code is right.. what's the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
Vector2 fuellevelPosition = new Vector2(50, 750);
Vector2 fuellevelTextPosition = fuellevelPosition + new Vector2(30, 0);
```

Why didn't your current code work? It should.

**Edit Based On Your Edit**

You can't use fuellevelPosition before it's initialized. Assuming that those two lines of code are inside the Game1 class, just assign them for now, like so.

```
Vector2 fuellevelPosition;
Vector2 fuellevelTextPosition;
```

Then, in the constructor function for Game1 set the variables, like so.

```
public Game1()
{
    fuellevelPosition = new Vector2(50, 750);
    fuellevelTextPosition = fuellevelPosition + new Vector2(30, 0);
}
```

Comment: I get a red line below the fuellevelPosition and the error message is: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property ??

Comment: You are going to have to show us more of your code.

Comment: I edited my answer to suit your update.

Comment: You're right! I didn't thought of that! Thanks!